# Weebly and Mathjax

Tags: mathjax, weebly

I have tried the four or so answers here to display MathJax on weebly (free account). Is there any way that would actually produce **inline** equations?

Any hint would be super appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Why the downvote? It is a legitimate question I would think...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

---

## MathJax

I took the example from here: http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/basic/mathematics.html#basic-mathematics

[image]

---

## Steps

1. Go to your Weebly theme section and click on *Edit HTML/CSS*.

[image]

2. Edit the header.html and place this snippet inside it:

`<script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=es6"></script>`
`<script type="text/javascript" id="MathJax-script" async src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-chtml.js"></script>`

[image]

3. Add your equation inline using 'Embed Code'.

[image]

4. Voila! (It still might render as LaTex code in the editor but will show up as proper equation when you publish the page.)

[image]

Comment: Hi Hackinet, many thanks! Is there a </script> missing, maybe? I think I got it to work but after I edited the no-header.html? Just clarifying to make this useful for others. thanks again!

Comment: Yes, there was a `</script>` missing. Thanks. However, there are only two scripts (that I mentioned in the answer), those are the only ones needed to be included in your `header.html` or `no-header.html` (in your case, since you aren't using a header). If this answer solves your issue, do mark it as the accepted answer so it's useful for others. :D @max_zorn